# How do i change the material of a object separate from the script

Tags: materials

I just need to know how to change the material of an object from another's script so that I don't have to make a script in the other object and change the material from their.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using Unity, since you didn't mention that...anywhere? Presumably you clicked on the Renderer's Materials field and swapped out the material you want to use there? In what way does this not serve your needs?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't list what engine or programming language you are using I'm going to assume it is Unity and C# since that is where most beginners get started. If writing a script to switch materials is pretty simple you just need referenced to the objects you want to change or if it is attached to the object you want to change, you can just get references. I think you want to change one object material from a second object in which case something like the code below should work.

In the future, please try to be a bit more detailed in your questions. The more vague they are the more difficult it is to help. I hope that doesn't come off as rude, but I honestly have no idea if the script below solves your problem since it is designed for Unity and not another engine like Unreal.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MaterialChangingScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool changeMaterial = false;
    public Material nextMaterial;
    private Material originalMaterial;
    public Renderer target;

    private void Awake()
    {
        originalMaterial = target.material;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (changeMaterial)
        {
            changeMaterial = false;
            ChangeMaterial();
        }
    }

    private void ChangeMaterial()
    {
        target.material = target.material == originalMaterial ? nextMaterial : originalMaterial;
    }
}
```